# How to deal with unwanted cursor movement during logic test

Tags: save-excursion

I have a function that tests if another nested pair of parenthesis exits or not.

```el
(defun next-pair-exists-in (func)
  "Check if inner or outer pair exists.
Function employs `up-list` or `down-list` as argument to work."
  (progn
    (forward-char)
    (let ((rslt
           (not (eql (point)
                     (progn (ignore-errors (funcall func))
                            (point))))))
      (backward-char)
      rslt)))
```

I use it to implement parenthesis integrity in Chinese texts, where double quotes must be nested within single quotes and vice versa `「『「」』」`.

```el
(defun paren-integrity ()
  "Double quote must follow single quote."
  (interactive)
  (outer-paren) ;; bring cursor to outermost parenthesis
  ;; check that two levels exist for the test.
  (if (and (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)
           (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list))
      (progn (single-quote-test) ;; make sure single quote is at point and move inwards.
             (double-quote-test))
    (single-quote-test)))
```

`single-quote-test` and `double-quote-test` just makes sure the character at point is a single or double quote and move to the next nested pair of quotes, if they exist.

One problem I encounter is that running `(and (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)(next-pair-exists-in #'down-list))` itself brings the cursor inwards by 2 levels.

> |「1「2「3「4「5」」」」」--> 「1「|2「3「4「5」」」」」

So when the actual code starts to run, it runs on 3 and 4 instead of the intended 1 and 2 the logic test is meant for:

> 「1「2「3『4「5」4』3」2」1」

How do I get `(next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)` to return a `t`/`nil` value without moving the cursor?

---

## Desired Outcome:

> 「1『2「3『4「5」4』3」2』1」

---

## The Whole Codebase as it sits at present for testing purposes

```el
;;;; Nested Parentheses 「『』」

(use-package smartparens)

(defun outer-paren ()
  "Move point to the outermost parenthesis."
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors
    (while t
      (up-list)))
  (sp-backward-sexp))

(defun next-pair-exists-in (func)
  "Check if inner or outer pair exists. 
Function employs `up-list` or `down-list` as argument to work."
  (progn 
    (forward-char)
    (let ((rslt
       (not (eql (point)
             (progn (ignore-errors (funcall func))
                (point))))))
      (backward-char)
      rslt)))

(defun is-single-quote ()
  "Check if symbol at point is 「."
  (eq ?「 (char-after)))

  (defun is-double-quote ()
    "Check if symbol at point is 『."
    (eq ?『 (char-after)))

    (defun is-open-quote ()
      "Check if symbol at point is 「."
      (or (eq ?「 (char-after))
          (eq ?『 (char-after))))

;;;;; Logic Functions

      (defun single-quote-test ()
        "Test to see if current pair is 「」. 
Replace『』 with 「」 if necessary. 
Move cursor to inner quote if it exists. "
        (interactive)
        ;; First condition: if it is 『』, change to 「」. 
        (cond ((is-double-quote)
           (let ((current-paren (remove-paren))) ;; `remove-paren` would execute the removal. 
             ;; subtract 1 from close-position (ie. second element of `current-paren`) 
             (setf (nth 1 current-paren) (1- (nth 1 current-paren)))          
             ;; subtract 2 to every point in `current-paren` to derive insertion position.
                    ;  (setq current-paren (mapcar (apply-partially #'- 2) current-paren))
             ;; insert relevant symbol to positions by pair.
             (insert-single-quote current-paren)
             (sp-backward-sexp)
             (if (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)
             (progn (down-list)
                (backward-char)))))
          ;; Second condition: if it is a 「」, move to next nested if it exists. 
          ((and (is-single-quote) 
            (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list))      
           (down-list)
           (backward-char))
          ;; `down-list` needs to be called twice because it brings point to content within the quote rather than on the quote itself.  
          (t nil)))

      (defun double-quote-test ()
        "Test to see if current pair is 「」. 
Replace『』 with 「」 if necessary. 
Move cursor to inner quote if it exists. "
        (interactive)
        ;; First condition: if it is 『』, change to 「」. 
        (cond ((is-single-quote)
           (let ((current-paren (remove-paren))) ;; `remove-paren` would execute the removal. 
             ;; subtract 1 from close-position (ie. second element of `current-paren`) 
             (setf (nth 1 current-paren) (1- (nth 1 current-paren)))          
             ;; subtract 2 to every point in `current-paren` to derive insertion position.
                    ;  (setq current-paren (mapcar (apply-partially #'- 2) current-paren))
             ;; insert relevant symbol to positions by pair.
             (insert-double-quote current-paren)
             (sp-backward-sexp)
             (if (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)
             (progn (down-list)
                (backward-char)))))
          ;; Second condition: if it is a 「」, move to next nested if it exists. 
          ((and (is-double-quote) 
            (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list))      
           (down-list)
           (backward-char))
          ;; `down-list` needs to be called twice because it brings point to content within the quote rather than on the quote itself.  
          (t nil)))

;;;;; Functions that handle 「」『』 in pairs

      (defun paren-position ()
        "Returns a list of positions where parenthesis has been sitting."
        (interactive)
        (if (is-open-quote)
        (setq paren-pos (list (point)
                      (progn (sp-forward-sexp) (point))))
          (setq paren-pos (list
                   (progn (sp-backward-sexp) (point))
                   (progn (sp-forward-sexp) (point))))))

      (defun remove-paren ()
        "Delete pair of parenthesis at point. 
Return the position of point and its counterpart."
        (interactive)
        (let ((current-paren (paren-position)))
          (if (is-open-quote)
          (forward-char)
        (backward-char))
          (sp-unwrap-sexp)
          current-paren))

      (defun insert-single-quote (current-paren)
            (progn (goto-char (nth 0 current-paren))
           (insert "「")
           (goto-char (nth 1 current-paren))
           (insert "」")))

      (defun insert-double-quote (current-paren)
            (progn (goto-char (nth 0 current-paren))
           (insert "『")
           (goto-char (nth 1 current-paren))
           (insert "』")))

      ;; Set the rule

      (defun paren-integrity ()
        "Double quote must follow single quote."
        (interactive)
        (save-excursion
          (outer-paren)
          (while (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)
        (backward-up-list)
        (if (and (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)
             (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list))
            (progn (backward-up-list 2)
               (single-quote-test)
               (double-quote-test))
          (if (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)
              (single-quote-test))))))
```

Comment: "suppressing its side-effect" could mean absolutely anything in general, so the question title isn't very useful as-is (as there is no magic "suppress all side-effects" feature).  In this very specific case, are you looking for `save-excursion` ?

Comment: I have `save-excursion` in my original code. Removed it to demonstrate how the cursor travels. It doesn't really make a difference. I think what it does is just to bring the cursor back to its original position when the code has run its course. What I need is a function that suppresses the functional component of `down-list` when `(next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)` is called. `symbol-value` doesn't work either.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  If you're calling a function but you don't want its "functional component" to do anything, then why are you calling it?  If you want *some* of it to have an effect but not *all* of it, then say *exactly* what it is that you want to suppress or revert, otherwise how can anyone answer the question?

Comment: I want `(next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)` to just return a `t` or `nil` value without `down-list` moving the cursor inwards.

Comment: So as I said before: `(save-excursion (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list))` should solve that problem.

Comment: `(save-excursion (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list))` doesn't produce the logic test I need because the cursor would not be traveling for the test. I think I need some way of separating the cursor position of logic testing from the actual code itself.

Comment: Whatever it is, I just need to code to be able to produce `「1『2「3『4「5」』」』」` from `1「2「3「4「5」」」」」`.

Comment: @phils Thanks for the comment. It helped clarify my thoughts. In retrospect, what I am asking was how to prevent necessary cursor movement during the logic test from affecting the actual code that I was about to run. The answer is surprisingly simple: Move the cursor back before running the code!

Comment: If need be you can always remember the position you (potentially) want to return to, and use `goto-char` to jump back to it more directly.  E.g. `(let (pos) ... (setq pos (point)) ... (if condition (goto-char pos) ...) ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

further to my comment on your own answer something like this makes more sense to me as the check doesnt alter anything.

```el
    (defun next-pair-exists-in (func)
      "Check if inner or outer pair exists.
    Function employs `up-list` or `down-list` as argument to work."
      (setq-local reslt nil)
      (save-excursion
        (forward-char)
        (setq rslt
              (not (eql (point)
                        (progn (ignore-errors (funcall func))
                               (point))))))
      rslt)
```

Obviously you would need to undo your "undo" code in the calling function and also specifically advance in your calling code.

Comment: What's the difference between `(setq-local reslt nil)` and `(let ...)` in terms of keeping variables local? Does it matter if `result` and `rslt` don't match?

Comment: How do I rewrite this code so that I can use `(next-pair-exists-in #'down-list 2)` to call it twice like `(backward-up-list 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem. I use `backward-up-list` to undo the cursor movement during the conditional before running the actual code.

```el
(defun paren-integrity ()
  "Double quote must follow single quote."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (outer-paren)
    (while (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)
      (backward-up-list)
      (if (and (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)
               (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list))
          (progn (backward-up-list 2)
                 (single-quote-test)
                 (double-quote-test))
        (if (next-pair-exists-in #'down-list)
            (single-quote-test))))))
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Could you please provide the code for your quote exists functions. I would suggest that next-pair-exists-in should be called pair-exists-in (you can pass multiple functions to it) and look after restoring cursor position itself (it is, after all, a predicate that should have no side effects) - and then you specifically advance when it returns true –

Comment: @RichieHH I am sharing the rest of the code for testing purposes. Please help see if there is anything else I can improve on. `paren-integrity` is working correctly now. Next thing I would like to do is write a function for lateral testing `「『』『』」` and join the two together.